# Kali Linux and Windows in the same partition on C Drive

Tags: linux, windows

I have a very serious problem, I have installed Kali and Windows in the same partition dual-boot, So I want to delete Kali so what I have to do, should I make back up for windows then format the c Drive and how to fix the dual-boot problem, And I Don't have that experience in Kali I'm just new on that filed. 
Thank you.

Comment: "in the same partition" are you sure?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Comment: Wrong site, SO is for programming question, try https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong site but I'll answer while I took the time to tell you the question was asked on the wrong site.

You don't have Kali -- which is Debian Linux -- and Windows on the same partition.  You have them on the same drive perhaps; but not on the same partition.

1. Open Computer Management -> Go to Disk Management.
2. For the partition which is NOT your Windows stuff, right click on it choose Delete Volume.
3. Insert your Windows recovery disk.  If you don't have one, the install disk will work but you many need to perform some extra steps (Google will be your friend) than these:

3a.  Boot from the disk.

3b.  Select Repair Your Computer.

3c.  Select Troubleshoot.

3d.  Select the option for Command Prompt if one doesn't come up.

4d.  Type: bootrec /fixmbr.

That will clobber the Linux information in the boot sector and allow you go directly into Windows when your box reboots.

I recommend running chkdsk c: /b /v /r /f and defrag c: /v /f afterwards as well.

HTH.